# How to make list with sublists based on pattern(word) from a input list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sublist

I have a list where particular block of statements separated by foo like follows:

```
a=['E3P.B99990001.pdb_138:6.923:0.241:6.116',  'E3P.B99990001.pdb_397:15.856:3.506:8.144', 'foo',

'E3P.B99990002.pdb_138:4.499:4.286:8.260', 'E3P.B99990002.pdb_397:14.897:3.238:9.338',  'foo']
```

Here, I want to make a Mainlist with sublists for each blog which is seperated by pattern "foo" like follows.

```
Mainlist=[
            ['E3P.B99990001.pdb_138:6.923:0.241:6.116',
             'E3P.B99990001.pdb_397:15.856:3.506:8.144']#sublist1 (read input list values until first "foo" and make first sublist)

            ['E3P.B99990002.pdb_138:6.923:0.241:6.116',
             'E3P.B99990002.pdb_397:15.856:3.506:8.144']#sublist2 (read input list values until first "foo" to second "foo" and make second sublist)
```

Main Idea is make a different sublist by using "foo" is delimiter
                                                                          ]

I hope its understandable. if some one knows could you help me out of it.

Thanking you in advance

CODE BASED ON #Brien gives exact answer:

```
sub = []
for item in a:
    if item == 'foo':
        ATOM_COORDINATE.append(a)
        sub = []
    else:
        a.append(item)
print sub
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
['E3P.B99990001.pdb_138:6.923:0.241:6.116', 'E3P.B99990001.pdb_397:15.856:3.506:8.144', 'E3P.B99990001.pdb_424:8.558:1.315:6.627', 'E3P.B99990001.pdb_774:14.204:-5.490:24.812', 'E3P.B99990001.pdb_865:15.545:4.258:10.007', 'E3P.B99990001.pdb_929:16.146:-6.081:24.770'],
['E3P.B99990002.pdb_138:4.499:4.286:8.260', 'E3P.B99990002.pdb_397:14.897:3.238:9.338', 'E3P.B99990002.pdb_424:5.649:5.914:8.639', 'E3P.B99990002.pdb_774:12.114:-6.864:23.897', 'E3P.B99990002.pdb_865:15.200:3.910:11.227', 'E3P.B99990002.pdb_929:13.649:-6.894:22.589']
                                               ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# assuming your original list is called biglist
Mainlist = []
sublist = []
for item in biglist:
    if item == 'foo':
        Mainlist.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
    else:
        sublist.append(item)
```

Comment: my original list is: a=['E3P.B99990001.pdb_138:6.923:0.241:6.116',  'E3P.B99990001.pdb_397:15.856:3.506:8.144', 'foo',

'E3P.B99990002.pdb_138:4.499:4.286:8.260', 'E3P.B99990002.pdb_397:14.897:3.238:9.338',  'foo']

Comment: sub = []
for item in a:
    if item == 'foo':
        ATOM_COORDINATE.append(a)
        sub = []
    else:
        a.append(item)
It works fine

Comment: To indicate to other people that this was helpful for you, consider accepting this answer.